# How can I sort a Python string list based on the base part of an item?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a Python list like the following.

```
lst =[
"C123, ABC, 10",
"C456, DEF, 30",
"C789, GHI, 20"
.................
]
```

I want to sort the list in descending order based on the third part of an item so that the output should look like the following.

```
lst =[
"C456, DEF, 30",
"C789, GHI, 20",
"C123, ABC, 10"
.................
]
```

How can I do it? Please let me know.

Comment: Use the `key` option to `list.sort()` to extract the part you want to sort on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [key-function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).

`list.sort()`:

```
lst.sort(key = lambda x: x.split(" ")[2], reverse=True)

lst
```

Or `sorted()`:

```
sorted(lst, key = lambda x: x.split(" ")[2], reverse=True)
```

**Output**:

```
['C456, DEF, 30', 'C789, GHI, 20', 'C123, ABC, 10']
```

Comment: The current implementation is considering third part of the item as string. How I can consider it as an integer?

Comment: do you mean something like `sorted(lst, key = lambda x: int(x.split(" ")[2]), reverse=True)` ?